# Testing a Class with a Static Class/method dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, mocking

So I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyClassToTest()
{
    MyStaticClass.DoSomethingThatIsBadForUnitTesting();
}
```

and a static class that looks like this:

```
public static class MyStaticClass()
{
    public static void DoSomethingThatIsBadForUnitTesting()
    {
        // Hit a database
        // call services
        // write to a file
        // Other things bad for unit testing
    }
}
```

(Obviously this is a dumbed down example)

So, I know that the second class is doomed when it comes to unit testing, but is there any way to uncouple the `MyClassToTest` class so that I can test it (WITHOUT instantiating `MyStaticClass`).  Basically, I would want it to ignore this call.

Note: Sadly this is a Compact Framework Project, so tools like Moles and Typemock Isolator cannot be used :(.

Comment: what language?  I can think of a few things in Python but this looks like Java.

Comment: @wheaties - sorry I should have said... C# (Visual Studio 2008)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Define an interface that does the same thing as `DoSomethingThatIsBadForUnitTesting`, for instance:

```
public interface IAction {
    public void DoSomething();
}
```

(Obviously, in real code, you'd pick better names.)

Then you can write a simple wrapper for the class for use in production code:

```
public class Action : IAction {
    public void DoSomething() {
        MyStaticClass.DoSomethingThatIsBadForUnitTesting();
    }
}
```

In `MyClassToTest`, you pass in an instance of `IAction` via its constructor and call the method on that instance instead of the static class. In production code, you pass in the concrete class `Action` so the code behaves as before. In the unit test, you pass in a mock object that implements `IAction`, either using a mock framework or rolling your own mock.

Comment: +1 Good answer. the OP said "WITHOUT instantiating MyStaticClass" - and the point is you need to instantiate SOMETHING in order to benefit from dynamic method binding here.

Comment: +1, This is the first step toward no longer implementing static calls with side effects or statically-accessed Singletons.  The adapter objects can help you get existing code with static dependencies under test.  Ultimately, aim toward pulling out the problematic static calls entirely.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for. And now I realise how bad our applications are since they're peppered with static calls for no good reason.